# JavaScript access parent scope

Tags: javascript, scope, parent, javascript-objects

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access the parent's class scope. My code is as follows

```
var Class = function(){
    this.smth = 3;
}

Class.prototype.setters = {};
Class.prototype.setters.smth = function(smth){
    this.smth = smth;
}
```

However this of course does not work, it affects `smth` to `Class.setters`. I tried using `.bind(Class.prototype);` to no avail.
Does anyone have a solution? I've got plenty of sub-methods.

Comment: If I understood you well, you want to create a method to set `smth`, in this case `Class.prototype.setSmth = function (smth) { this.smth = smth; };`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @smarber no sorry, maybe i did not explain well. That's just the example. I want to create sub-methods capable of accessing 'this' from the parent class.

Comment: There is "scope" in objects?

Comment: @JoColina Just do not use "sub-methods". Use proper own methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `someInstance.setters.smth(...)` the `this` of the function call is the `settings` object, and there's no way for that `smth` function to know *how* the `settings` object is being accessed, only that it is being provided as a `this`.

You could keep your desired syntax but at significant memory cost by creating a unique `setters` object for each instance, inside your constructor:

```
var Class = function(){
    var thisClassInstance = this;
    this.smth = 3;
    this.setters = {};
    this.setters.smth = function(smth){
        thisClassInstance.smth = smth;
    }
}
```

This is suboptimal because you lose the benefits of prototype inheritance; each instance has a suite of unique functions in the `setters` object and nothing is shared.

A leaner way would be to have each instance has its own `setters` object that knows the identity of its parent instance, but that `setters` object inherits all its methods from a prototype setter object:

```
// all `setters` object inherit their methods from this object
var settersPrototype = {};

// methods on the `setters` set values on `this.parent`
settersPrototype.smth = function(smth){
    this.parent.smth = smth;
}

var Class = function(){
    this.smth = 3;

    // this instance has a `setters` object that inherits all its methods
    this.setters = Object.create(settersPrototype);
    this.setters.parent = this;
}
```

This way, you have a mild memory cost of a unique `{ parent: ... }` object per instance, but there is a single prototype version each setter function, present on the one-and-only `settersPrototype` object.

Comment: What worked was adding the `this.<nameOfSubMethod>.parent = this;` Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few ways.  There are others with your prototype approach, but this might make it a bit more clear:

ES5

```
var TestClassEs5 = function(){
    // With ES5, store the outer this to variable to preserve
    var self = this;
    this.smth = 3;

    this.setters = {
      smth: function (smth) {
        self.smth = smth;
      }
    }

    return this;
}
```

ES6

```
const TestClassEs6 = function(){
    this.smth = 3;

    // Using a fat arrow syntax binds the function to the lexical scope
    this.setters = {
      smth: (smth) => this.smth = smth
    }

    return this;
}
```

JS Bin: 
http://jsbin.com/qugatacive/edit?js,console